# Spark error: Unsupported literal type class sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

> Spark error: Unsupported literal type class sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema

```
val crimeDF = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("crime_data.csv")
crimeDF.show(5)
```

[image]

```
var a = crimeDF.select(max($"IncidntNum")).take(1)
println(a(0).toString)

 a: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([991309046])
    [991309046]
```

I am executing this command:

```
crimeDF.where($"IncidntNum ===" +a(0))
```

but getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema [991309046]
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
  at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:162)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:95)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.$plus(Column.scala:648)
  ... 76 elided
```

Comment: I proposed `crimeDF.where($"IncidntNum" === a(0))` in a now deleted answer, but apparently it didn't work either. Shouldn't it be `IncidentNum` anyway?

Comment: Maybe you should provide more information about what `crimeDF` and `a` are. Try to come up with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: same error
where($"IncidntNum" === lit( a(0) ) ) while executing this command

Comment: what is a(0) or a ?

Comment: **For VtC's:** after two solution attempts by me and another commenter who now deleted his comment with another solution proposal, it looks more like "Unclear" rather than "Trivial typo". I couldn't confirm that it is merely a trivial typo, because the example is not compilable. Whatever `a` is, catalyst doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: As per your suggestions, I have made the desired amendment and Now i hope it would be clear

Comment: Thanks everyone for your time

Comment: It help me a alot

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to pass an entire `Row` as a literal. Extract the value from the row before using it in subsequent queries:

```
crimeDF.where($"IncidntNum" === a(0).getInt(0))
```

or

```
crimeDF.where($"IncidntNum" === a(0).getString(0))
```

depending on whether those numbers in your output are `Int`s or `String`s.

Comment: I got this error

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.unboxToInt(BoxesRunTime.java:101)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Row$class.getInt(Row.scala:223)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRow.getInt(rows.scala:165)
  ... 77 elided

Comment: @AmanRaturi Well, then it's a `String`, not an `Int`. Do `getAs[String]` instead. How am I supposed to tell whether `991309046` is stored as String or as an Int, if you are not providing the fully compilable code... Ok, actually, I could have inferred that from the fact that you are just loading a CSV-file, which produces a bunch of rows with strings. Still: no standalone compilable / executable example, that's the outcome...

Comment: @ Andrey Tyukin Thanks for your support

Comment: @AmanRaturi You are welcome. However, "Thank you"-comments are [not really what the comment section should be used for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (see also [this answer on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184)), because they do not help to improve the answer, and therefore do not contribute anything to the content. Use the [answer acceptance mechanism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) instead. Moreover, the `@`-notification mechanism doesn't work with spaces [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019).

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing

```
var a = crimeDF.select(max($"IncidntNum")).take(1)(0).getAs[Int](0)
```

and then

```
crimeDF.where($"IncidntNum" === a)
```

or

```
crimeDF.where($"IncidntNum" === lit(a))
```

Comment: can you please me with this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374838/unsupported-literal-type-class-scala-runtime-boxedunit