# Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, datastax, databricks

I am trying to filter a column of a dataframe read from oracle as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, lit, when}

val df0  =  df_org.filter(col("fiscal_year").isNotNull())
```

When I do it I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.apply(literals.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$$anonfun$create$2.apply(literals.scala:163)
at scala.util.Try.getOrElse(Try.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Literal$.create(literals.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.typedLit(functions.scala:113)
at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.lit(functions.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.sql.Column.apply(Column.scala:212)
at com.snp.processors.BenchmarkModelValsProcessor2.process(BenchmarkModelValsProcessor2.scala:80)
at com.snp.utils.Utils$$anonfun$getAllDefinedProcessors$1.apply(Utils.scala:30)
at com.snp.utils.Utils$$anonfun$getAllDefinedProcessors$1.apply(Utils.scala:30)
at com.sp.MigrationDriver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MigrationDriver.scala:140)
at com.sp.MigrationDriver$$anonfun$main$6$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(MigrationDriver.scala:140)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at com.sp.MigrationDriver$$anonfun$main$6.apply(MigrationDriver.scala:138)
at com.sp.MigrationDriver$$anonfun$main$6.apply(MigrationDriver.scala:135)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
at scala.collection.MapLike$DefaultKeySet.foreach(MapLike.scala:174)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
at com.sp.MigrationDriver$.main(MigrationDriver.scala:135)
at com.sp.MigrationDriver.main(MigrationDriver.scala)
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here and how to fix this?

Comment: please add more information about versions of Spark, and Spark Cassandra connector...

Comment: @AlexOtt , sir  Here are the version details :
scala - 2.11
spark - 2.3.1
cassandra - 3.11.1

Comment: and spark-cassandra-connector version?

Comment: what do you mean by "trying to filter a column of a dataframe"? can you elaborate that?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan , column "fiscal_year" seems to have some null values , hence failing to load into cassandra ...so from dataframe filtering out those records.

Comment: @AlexOtt sir, its <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.0</version>

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727742/how-to-filter-out-a-null-value-from-spark-dataframe for filtering and you can check my answer too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50478512/filter-null-value-in-dataframe-column-of-spark-scala

Comment: @RameshMaharjan  I am getting similar error while filtering ...how to fix it   ....  result_df.filter( col("indicator") === lit('N'))     .... ERROR ::: RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class java.lang.Character N

Comment: isn't the error message clear enough? @user3252097 ? character is not supported in lit function

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try removing `()` in `isNull()` in your filter.

Comment: What? there is no `isNull` in the OP's question

Comment: he means to remove the parenthesis on `isNotNull`, which is the correct answer.

Comment: So this totally worked for me but WHY? What is going on?

Answer (score 20):

Just remove parenthesis on your function:

from:
`val df0 = df_org.filter(col("fiscal_year").isNotNull())`
to:
`val df0 = df_org.filter(col("fiscal_year").isNotNull)`