# spark dataframe with column when condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My requirement is as below

Joined two data frames as below:

```
     var c = a.join(b,keys,"fullouter")
```

c.printSchema() as below:

```
     |-- add: string (nullable = true)
     |-- sub: string (nullable = true)
     |-- delete: string (nullable = true)
     |-- mul: long (nullable = true)
     |-- ADD: string (nullable = true)
     |-- SUB: string (nullable = true)
     |-- DELETE: string (nullable = true)
     |-- MUL: long (nullable = true)
      It's good until here.
```

Now i am doing a withcolumn when condition as below

```
     val d = c.withColumn("column", when(c("a.add") === c("b.ADD"), 
   "Neardata"))
```

error as below:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 
    Cannot resolve column name "a.add"
```

I tried as below also

```
     val d = c.withColumn("column", when(col("a.add") === col("b.ADD"), "Neardata"))

    Again error.

   Please suggest.
```

Comment: could you add `c.printSchema()` output into the question?

Comment: Here you go :|-- add: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sub: string (nullable = true)
 |-- delete: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mul: long (nullable = true)
 |-- ADD: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SUB: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DELETE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MUL: long (nullable = true)

Comment: Dear @sparkscala have you defined aliases to 2 dataframe before you refer them in when ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define alias with datframe.as("a") and dataframe1.as("b")

Example :

```
  import spark.sqlContext.implicits._
  val data = List(("James","","Smith","36636","M",60000),
    ("Michael","Rose","","40288","M",70000),
    ("Robert","","Williams","42114","",400000),
    ("Maria","Anne","Jones","39192","F",500000),
    ("Jen","Mary","Brown","","F",0))

  val cols = Seq("first_name","middle_name","last_name","dob","gender","salary")
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(cols:_*).as("a")
  val df2 = df.withColumn("a.new_gender", when(col("a.gender") === "M","Male")
    .when(col("a.gender") === "F","Female")
    .otherwise("Unknown")).show
```

Output :

```
+----------+-----------+---------+-----+------+------+------------+
|first_name|middle_name|last_name|  dob|gender|salary|a.new_gender|
+----------+-----------+---------+-----+------+------+------------+
|     James|           |    Smith|36636|     M| 60000|        Male|
|   Michael|       Rose|         |40288|     M| 70000|        Male|
|    Robert|           | Williams|42114|      |400000|     Unknown|
|     Maria|       Anne|    Jones|39192|     F|500000|      Female|
|       Jen|       Mary|    Brown|     |     F|     0|      Female|
+----------+-----------+---------+-----+------+------+------------+
```

I think with out alias you are trying to access like this... that might be the cause.

```
  val df2 = df.withColumn("df.new_gender", when(col("df.gender") === "M","Male")
    .when(col("df.gender") === "F","Female")
    .otherwise("Unknown")).show
```

Comment: Tried above and i am getting the below error  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()

Comment: what is the version of spark and scala

Comment: basically of you are using string in when otherwise you have to enclose with lit("") for ex :  `lit("Neardata")` for that you need to import org.apache.sql.functions._

Comment: can you print the code here, where you are getting error ?

Comment: I have defined alias for a & b and the code is as below                                                   
  val d = c.withColumn("column", when(c("a.add") === c("b.ADD"),  "Neardata"))                 spark 2.3 scala 2.11.8

Comment: try  lit("Neardata") this is another issue not reated to aliases

Comment: `df.withColumn("column", when(df("a.first_name") === df("b.first_name"),
    "Neardata"))
}` is right.... you are getting this error some where else what is complete stacktrace ?

Comment: Sorry about that. Yes c is a dataframe. The actual code is as below                                                val d =c.withColumn("column", when(c("a.add") === c("b.ADD"), "Neardata")
                       .when(c("a.add").isNull(), "INSERT"))  .                                               Your response is very much appreciated.

Comment: `df.withColumn("column",
    when(df("a.first_name") === df("a.first_name"), "Neardata")
    .when(df("a.middle_name").isNull, "INSERT")).show
` will work no error for me...

Comment: `+----------+-----------+---------+-----+------+------+--------+
|first_name|middle_name|last_name|  dob|gender|salary|  column|
+----------+-----------+---------+-----+------+------+--------+
|     James|           |    Smith|36636|     M| 60000|Neardata|
|   Michael|       Rose|         |40288|     M| 70000|Neardata|
|    Robert|           | Williams|42114|      |400000|Neardata|
|     Maria|       Anne|    Jones|39192|     F|500000|Neardata|
|       Jen|       Mary|    Brown|     |     F|     0|Neardata|
+----------+-----------+---------+-----+------+------+--------+
`

Comment: try to follow the example given above.

Comment: it's working fine till df.withColumn("column", when(df("a.first_name") === df("a.first_name"), "Neardata") after that if i add the other statement  .when(df("a.middle_name").isNull, "INSERT")) it's failing with the same error                           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()

Comment: its not possible as per above it should work. do one thing make it 2 steps 1) val df1 = df.withColumn("column",
    when(df("a.first_name") === df("a.first_name"), "Neardata"))
  
  
  2) ` df1.withColumn("column",when(df("a.middle_name").isNull, "INSERT"))`

Comment: Splitted into 2 dataframes and both are failing . It's really strange. If i have only df1 then it's working. if i add df2 both are failing.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported literal type class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit ()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53374838/unsupported-literal-type-class-scala-runtime-boxedunit I think u have same isue check this

Comment: if you are using isNull() then remove () it will be isNull

Comment: please cultivate the habbit of accepting the answer if you find useful.